# Configuring Maven, jenkins with Sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have installed Jenkins and Sonar, both work fine. I am able to build a maven android project using Jenkins. No i want to run Sonar on the android project. I have installed the Sonar plugin in Jenkins. Configured the sonar module in the configure system module and added a post build task for sonar to run

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:sonar: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:sonar in nbs-repo (http://10.10.2.89:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:sonar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at
```

My nexus installation works fine ? What am i doing wrong. My maven pom.xml does not contain any sonar plugin. What am i doing wrong?

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you tried cleanning your local repository?

Comment: Hi, please, have you found any solution of this isssue?

Answer (score 0):

1. From the error message its clear that mvn is trying to download the [sonar-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.sonar%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sonar-maven3-plugin%22) from your local Nexus repository which does not seem to have it.
2. Try `mvn -U` in the build in case you already have the plugin.This overrides the negative cache. Another thing is `<updatepolicy>` in your `settings.xml`
3. If you don't have the plugin and neither does your Nexus connect to the internet, you have to manually download and upload in Nexus of course. Please remember to match the version of the plugin with the SONAR installation. Also there would be a few (7-10) transitive dependencies with the plugin which you will need. I suggest using `mvn -X` or `mvn -e` to see a verbose output during your testing.